# In app purchase error while purchasing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm doing in app purchase (non consumable),When I make purchase it pop's up a alert view displaying "**you've already purchased item but hasn't been downloaded**" and transaction gets failed.Even after restarting Xcode and switch off/on device it remains same.I have a restore button,by tapping that I could restore the items.

After tapping restore it calls `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`

```
- (IBAction)Restore:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];


}
-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
    [self UnlockPurchase];
}
```

But this never goes to following method:

```
 case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Restored ");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
```

When I tested with other test user account the above function `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` gets called I have no issue when I restore.
I've tested in two devices were I have no issue in iPhone 5 running iOS 7.But running in iPhone 4(iOS 6),it pops up alert view for login (test user that never enters `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`)initially when I run the app.I guess its  because of unfinished transaction, but this test user account that I use it never enters `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`(where other accounts do enter).How to get rid of that login alert happens automatically ? and the issue happens only when I test in iPhone 4 ! Is this because of unfinished transaction or test user account issue or some other ? I have no clue please help !

Comment: Unfortunately the store kit is notoriously inaccurate when testing in sandbox mode. This has even been admitted by Apple engineers. Sadly, for the past few years, when I have store kit code at a stage where it makes sense that it works, and generally the testing is going well, then I assume that it's fine and move on. Somehow I've gotten by without any problems.

Comment: I might have never cared about this specific user account causing me problem but this pops up a login alert when I use my app.Thats the one thing ruins me @GuyKogus

Answer (score 0):

When do you call `removeTransactionObserver`?

In the past I've had an issue where I was removing the observer too early and it was creating a backlog of incomplete purchases and only one could be completed at a time.

I fixed it by moving the `removeTransactionObserver` call to `dealloc`

Comment: Yes I've done that in my purchase view controller like this '- (void)dealloc {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
}'